# CSS class issue in simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I have multiple div with Classes like below

```
<div  class ="hub_categoryDeal Dubai  Healthcare BEAUTY HAIR_REMOVAL1 LASER_HAIR_REMOVAL Dubai"
<div  class ="hub_categoryDeal Dubai  Healthcare SERVICES HAIR_REMOVAL1 LASER_HAIR_REMOVAL Dubai"
```

The difference is Type name like `BEAUTY` and `SERVICES` in the class.How i can get it in simple html find() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know/can't find the right array function for this but you can get all the classes then filter them. Like this:

```
$html_string = '<div  class ="hub_categoryDeal Dubai  Healthcare BEAUTY HAIR_REMOVAL1 LASER_HAIR_REMOVAL Dubai"></div>"
<div  class ="hub_categoryDeal Dubai  Healthcare SERVICES HAIR_REMOVAL1 LASER_HAIR_REMOVAL Dubai"></div>';
$html = str_get_html($html_string);

$classes = array();
foreach ($html->find('div.hub_categoryDeal') as $element) {
    // push all the values inside the container
    $classes = array_merge($classes, array_filter(explode(' ', $element->class)));
}
$temp = array_count_values($classes); // check all the values
foreach($temp as $key => $count) {
    if($count > 1) { // if is repeated
        $found = array_keys($classes, $key); // get all the repeated thru their keys
        if($found) {
            foreach($found as $k) {
                unset($classes[$k]); // remove them
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($classes);
```

Should output like:

```
Array
(
    [3] => BEAUTY
    [10] => SERVICES
)
```

Answer (score 0):

elements with BEAUTY in the class attribute:

```
$html->find('.BEAUTY')
```

elements with SERVICES in the class attribute:

```
$html->find('.SERVICES')
```